# javascript comparison not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

stockQty is 200 and $("#txtQty").val() is 5 but it always go inside else. Why? I get stockQty value from object and declare stockQty as global variable and use it from another function. I tried to output both value and they are 200 and 5. What's wrong?

```
if(stockQty>0 && $("#txtQty").val() <= stockQty){}
else{}
```

Comment: Prove us how it is not working?

Comment: @ksh try to alert value of $("#txtQty").val() and check whats the output

Comment: Yeah I already tried that. it's 5.

Comment: Question updated. Please check thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only time that 5 is bigger than 200 is when string comparison is used; and this only happens if both operands are strings, so you should make sure the values are of the proper type before making any comparison:

```
var inStock = +stockQty, // may have been a string
stockRequested = +$("#txtQty").val(); // definitely a string

if (stockRequested <= inStock) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nVd67/1/

```
var stockQty = 200;
if(stockQty>0 && $("#txtQty").val() <= stockQty){ alert('true')}
else{alert('false')}
```

Comment: I don't directly assign stockQty value. I get from object. If assign directly, it works.

Comment: The above code works as intended. You must either call the function before assigning the value of stockQty or you are assigning stockQty incorrectly. Have you tried debugging the javascript and keeping an eye on when stockQty updates?

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting string value . Use parseInt() to compare numeric value .

```
if(parseInt(stockQty)>0 && parseInt($("#txtQty").val()) <= parseInt(stockQty)){}
else{}
```

Comment: @jogesh_pi JuniorCoder is passing integer value var stockQty = 200 But is above question it is not specified .

Comment: why var stockQty = 200; In question stockQty only value is mentioned not type .@jogesh_pi

Comment: @ksh Just check your datatype using typeof operator . You will come to know exact reason .